# How can i read a file for urls and then launch all the urls in browser using python

Tags: python-2.7

In python 2.x , how can i read a file for urls and then launch all the urls in browser .

Launch a URL

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com')
```

How do i make it launch all the urls from a text file.

Urls linsted in text file as below:

http://google.com
http://yahoo.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    urls = content.split()
    for url in urls:
         webbrowser.open(url)
```

You can also try `webbrowser.open(url, 2)` to try to open the links in new tabs.